# How can I pass a variable from one JFrame To Another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, variables

I'm new to Java. I tried to find solution by myself but am not sure how to proceed.

I have 2 Jframes (JF1,JF2) , and I need to pass a variable from the JF1 to JF2

This is the code for JF1 : Note : i need the value x , value x get it from JTextfeild.

Can any one help me please

```
/*
 * JF1.java
 *
 * Created on 04 مايو, 2012, 09:01 م
 */

package finalpro;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author  OmaR
 */
public class JF1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form JF1 */
    public JF1() {
        initComponents();


    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        JB1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        JB3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        JB2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Online Test Creater");

        JB1.setText("Make");
        JB1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                JB1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        JB3.setText("Quit");
        JB3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                JB3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        JB2.setText("Reset");
        JB2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                JB2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setText("Number Of Question");

        jTextField1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jTextField1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setText("Main");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 127, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 64, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 50, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 128, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(34, 34, 34)))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(JB2)
                    .addComponent(JB3)
                    .addComponent(JB1)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addGap(30, 30, 30))
        );

        layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {JB1, JB2, JB3, jButton1});

        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                        .addComponent(JB1)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButton1))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(JB2)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(JB3)))
                .addContainerGap(37, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.VERTICAL, new java.awt.Component[] {JB1, JB2, JB3, jButton1});

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void JB3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        System.exit(0);
    }                                   

    private void JB2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jTextField1.setText("");

    }                                   

    private void JB1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:

            JF1 JFBU = new JF1()   ;
            JF2 JCreate = new JF2();

            this.setVisible(false);
        int  z = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());


          if (z == 0)
            {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " You Enter 0 Please write anumber ");

                 }
          else
          {
             JCreate.setVisible(true);
          }  


    }                                   

    private void jTextField1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Max Number of Questions Is 10");
    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        JFmain JFm = new JFmain();
        JFm.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);
    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               new JF1().setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton JB1;
    private javax.swing.JButton JB2;
    private javax.swing.JButton JB3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   


}
```

I have JF2, and I need to pass the Var z on it.

Comment: (offtopic) It's customary to name Java variable names using `lowercaseStartingCamelCase`.  As such, your declaration of `JFmain Jfm = new JFmain()` would be better as `JFmain jfm = new JFmain()`. Similarly your `JButton` variables

Comment: Thanks for you r comment i will start to do it

Answer (score 2):

Create constructor with parameter `int z`:

```
public class JF2 extends JFrame {
    private int z;

    public void setZ(int z) {
        this.z = z;
    }

    public int getZ() {
        return z;
    }

    public JF2(int z) {
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

And pass the variable `z` when you create the `JF2` -> `JF2 jCreate = new JF2(z);` or using setter `jCreate.setZ(z);`

Comment: Thanks for your help but really i dont know how to make it.... i try to pass inside the constractor but i get wrong >>> can i ask you i will make the JF1(int z) >>>> or in JF2 The main frame in JF1.... really thanks for your help and your time

Comment: Can you update your question with the stack trace of the exception or error that you got?

Comment: i dont have error but i cant pass the variable from Jframe to another

Comment: Are you familiar with OOP? If yes, all the snapshot example above is more clearly to solve your problem. If you still confusing with OOP you can email me and send your code and I'll help you find your problem.

Comment: Thanks Crazenezz for r u help and ur time .... im not that much familiar with OOP can i have your email please to contact you

Comment: Look at my profile for the [details](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1159948/crazenezz).