# Why do my string turn to null when I pass it from Jframe to Jframe?

Tags: java, string, swing, jframe, arguments

I have two JFrames, in my second one I added a private String and made a setter() for it:

```
public class FProduit extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private String CAT;

public void setCAT(String C) {
    this.CAT = C;
}
/*
***
*/
}
```

in my First JFrame, I have this:

```
FProduit Fp=new FProduit();

String cat=ButtonDisplay.getText().toString();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,cat);

Fp.setCAT(cat);
Fp.setVisible(true);
```

Which displays my String cat,and calls the second JFrame
but when I try to display it in my SECOND Jframe, like this:

```
public FProduit() {
initComponents();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,this.CAT);

}
```

all I get is a null String.

Comment: your code doesn't make sense. u used cat in a first section which looks like your main program and u reused it in the constructor of JFrame again?!!!how these are 2 different jframes?!!!!!

Comment: If your neighbor buys a big-screen TV and sets it up in his living room, does a matching one magically appear in your living room?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) 3) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: I actually referred to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10509413/3089045

I did exactly the same, in my code: 'cat' is a local variable in my first JFrame, and CAT is ANOTHER private variable  in the class FProduit (which is my SECOND JFrame).

I did exactly the same as the answer I linked above, only using strings not ints. Sorry me if I can't explain well enough my question (english is my third language)